I can't close the connection when my websocket connection is cut
I facing this issue from Tomcat and also I got this error:
[https-jsse-nio-443-exec-19]
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doClose Failed to close the ServletOutputStream connection cleanly

I need to close the connection automatically, when my websocket connection will be cut.

You might use AI as starting point, but always be aware that an AI-generated answer can be completely wrong even if it sounds very professional: e.g. https://www.phind.com/search?cache=rk35z2ws16y92qg59ri9kkd1
